# Javascript POST not working with .htaccess

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, post

On my upload page i do a post request with Javascript:

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "includes/parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

When i put my .htaccess file into my includes folder it won't work but if i delete it it will work so the problem is the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127.0.0.1
RewriteRule .* {domain} [R=302,L]
```

How can I allow the post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect rules don't work with `POST` data. Add a condition to skip redirect for `POST` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule .* {domain} [R=302,L]
```